# SQL database issue - TypeError in Python dask code

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, dask

I want to preprocess an SQL data table using the package dask in Python:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df_temporal = dd.read_sql_table('daily_data', 
                                'postgresql://schmid@cedar-pgsql-vm:5555/schmid_db',
                                'id')
print("Number null values: ", df_temporal['waterbody_id'].isnull().count().compute())
```

I get this error message for the code (line 46 is the last command shown above, with print()):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/6005341/schmidj/Preprocessing_temporal_data.py", line 46, in <module>
    print("Number null values: ", df_temporal['waterbody_id'].isnull().count().compute())
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 315, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 600, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 89, in get
    results = get_async(
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 511, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 319, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 224, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in <genexpr>
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/utils.py", line 71, in apply
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py", line 432, in _read_sql_chunk
    return df.astype(meta.dtypes.to_dict(), copy=False)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6231, in astype
    res_col = col.astype(dtype=cdt, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 6245, in astype
    new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 446, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 348, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 527, in astype
    new_values = astype_array_safe(values, dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 299, in astype_array_safe
    new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 230, in astype_array
    values = astype_nansafe(values, dtype, copy=copy)
  File "/home/schmidj/ANGLERENV/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/astype.py", line 170, in astype_nansafe
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

I assume the origin of the error is in the SQL data table 'daily_data' as the code works for another data table in the same database.

I also checked the database:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length, table_name,ordinal_position, is_nullable 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE table_name LIKE 'daily_data' 
ORDER BY ordinal_position;
```

and get this table:

```
   column_name                           |    data_type     | character_maximum_length | table_name | ordin
al_position | is_nullable 
-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+--------------------------+------------+------
------------+-------------
 waterbody_id                                                    | integer          |                          | daily_data |                1 | NO
 date                                                            | date             |                          | daily_data |                2 | YES
 minimum_air_temperature                                         | real             |                          | daily_data |              3 | YES
 air_temperature                                                 | real             |                          | daily_data |                4 | YES
 maximum_air_temperature                                         | real             |                          | daily_data |             5 | YES
 total_precipitation                                             | real             |                          | daily_data |                6 | YES
 dew_point_temperature                                           | real             |                          | daily_data |                7 | YES
 relative_humidity                                               | real             |                          | daily_data |                8 | YES
 wind_speed_at_10_meters                                         | real             |                          | daily_data |                9 | YES
 wind_direction                                                  | real             |                          | daily_data |               10 | YES
 solar_radiation                                                 | real             |                          | daily_data |               11 | YES
 atmospheric_pressure                                            | real             |                          | daily_data |               12 | YES
 snow_precipitation                                              | real             |                          | daily_data |               13 | YES
 snow_depth_accumulation                                         | real             |                          | daily_data |               14 | YES
 snow_water_equivalent                                           | real             |                          | daily_data |               15 | YES
 wind_speed_at_2_meters                                          | real             |                          | daily_data |               16 | YES
 degree_days                                                     | real             |                          | daily_data |               17 | YES
 is_in_tournament                                                | boolean          |                          | daily_data |               18 | NO
 closure_type                                                    | smallint         |                          | daily_data |               19 | NO
 total_trips                                                     | integer          |                          | daily_data |               20 | YES
 hours_out                                                       | double precision |                          | daily_data |               21 | YES
 catches                                                         | integer          |                          | daily_data |               22 | YES
 catch_rate_sum_div                                              | double precision |                          | daily_data |               23 | YES
 catch_rate_div_avg                                              | double precision |                          | daily_data |               24 | YES
 percent_tournament_total_trips                                  | double precision |                          | daily_data |               25 | YES
 percent_tournament_hours_out                                    | double precision |                          | daily_data |               26 | YES
 tournament_catch_rate_sum_div                                   | double precision |                          | daily_data |               27 | YES
 tournament_catch_rate_div_avg                                   | double precision |                          | daily_data |               28 | YES
 page_views                                                      | integer          |                          | daily_data |               29 | YES
 unique_page_views                                               | integer          |                          | daily_data |               30 | YES
 time_on_page                                                    | double precision |                          | daily_data |               31 | YES
 is_weekend                                                      | boolean          |                          | daily_data |               32 | NO
 is_holiday                                                      | boolean          |                          | daily_data |               33 | NO
 hours_worked_percent_change                                     | real             |                          | daily_data |               34 | YES
 natural_increase_of_population                                  | integer          |                          | daily_data |               35 | YES
 net_international_migration                                     | integer          |                          | daily_data |               36 | YES
 average_hourly_wages                                            | real             |                          | daily_data |               37 | YES
 consumer_price_index                                            | real             |                          | daily_data |               38 | YES
 was_stocked_this_year                                           | boolean          |                          | daily_data |               39 | YES
 weeks_since_last_stocked                                        | integer          |                          | daily_data |               40 | YES
 covid_cases_to_date                                             | integer          |                          | daily_data |               41 | YES
 covid_cases_daily                                               | integer          |                          | daily_data |               42 | YES
 covid_cases_last_seven_days                                     | integer          |                          | daily_data |               43 | YES
 province                                                        | text             |                          | daily_data |               44 | YES
 id                                                              | integer          |                          | daily_data |               45 | NO
 active_fishing_licenses_in_province                             | integer          |                          | daily_data |               46 | YES
 cumulative_trip_logs_member_distinct_in_fishing_period          | integer          |                          | daily_data |               47 | NO
 cumulative_trip_logs_member_distinct_in_fishing_period_by_provi | integer          |                          | daily_data |               48 | NO
```

This is the result how it should look like and what I got with the other data table:

```
df_static_test = dd.read_sql_table('waterbody', 'postgresql://schmidj@cedar-pgsql-vm:5555/schmidj_db', 'id')
print("Number null in static set surface_area: ", df_static_test['surface_area'].isnull().count().compute())
```

Output:

```
Number null in static set surface_area:  138991
```

I also tested the data types directly in Python:

```
print('Variable types in dataset: ', df_temporal.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
Variable types in dataset:  
waterbody_id                                                         int64
date                                                                object
minimum_air_temperature                                            float64
air_temperature                                                    float64
maximum_air_temperature                                            float64
total_precipitation                                                float64
dew_point_temperature                                              float64
relative_humidity                                                  float64
wind_speed_at_10_meters                                            float64
wind_direction                                                     float64
solar_radiation                                                    float64
atmospheric_pressure                                               float64
snow_precipitation                                                 float64
snow_depth_accumulation                                            float64
snow_water_equivalent                                              float64
wind_speed_at_2_meters                                             float64
degree_days                                                        float64
is_in_tournament                                                      bool
closure_type                                                         int64
total_trips                                                         object
hours_out                                                           object
catches                                                             object
catch_rate_sum_div                                                  object
catch_rate_div_avg                                                  object
percent_tournament_total_trips                                      object
percent_tournament_hours_out                                        object
tournament_catch_rate_sum_div                                       object
tournament_catch_rate_div_avg                                       object
page_views                                                          object
unique_page_views                                                   object
time_on_page                                                        object
is_weekend                                                            bool
is_holiday                                                            bool
hours_worked_percent_change                                         object
natural_increase_of_population                                       int64
net_international_migration                                          int64
average_hourly_wages                                               float64
consumer_price_index                                               float64
was_stocked_this_year                                               object
weeks_since_last_stocked                                            object
covid_cases_to_date                                                 object
covid_cases_daily                                                   object
covid_cases_last_seven_days                                         object
province                                                            object
active_fishing_licenses_in_province                                  int64
cumulative_trip_logs_member_distinct_in_fishing_period               int64
cumulative_trip_logs_member_distinct_in_fishing_period_by_provi      int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: what exactly is line 46?#, also you have a typo with 2 closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that it is an issue with dask as reading in the database with pandas didn't lead to any error. I also discovered that three variables lead to this error message. My solution is now to (1) read these three variables with pandas, (2) transform them to a dask dataframe and (3) concatenate them with the remaining dataset:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df_temporal_dd = dd.read_sql_table('daily_data', 
                            '[SQL_Database]',
                            'id',
                            columns=columns_sel)

# These columns lead to errors
columns_sel_error = ['natural_increase_of_population', 'net_international_migration', 'active_fishing_licenses_in_province']

df_temporal_pd = pd.read_sql('daily_data',
                            'postgresql://schmidj@cedar-pgsql-vm:5432/schmidj_db',
                            'id',
                            columns=columns_sel_error)

# Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a Dask DataFrame
df_temporal_pd = dd.from_pandas(df_temporal_pd, npartitions=2)

# Perform column-wise concatenation
df_temporal = dd.concat([df_temporal_dd, df_temporal_pd], axis=1)
```